# Eclipse feature based launch unable to resolve dependency

Tags: eclipse, dependencies, osgi, osgi-bundle, launch-configuration

I have an OSGI bundle that depends on a package, which is exposed through a feature. The
package I depend on requires a specific version of a bundle, say `com.company.antlr.runtime (3.0.1)`. The feature in turn packages two versions of the bundle, `com.company.antlr.runtime (3.0.1)` and `com.company.antlr.runtime (3.2.0)`.

The problem is that when I make a feature based launch configuration in Eclipse with my bundle (in a feature) and the feature containing the package I depend on, I get a missing constraint
validation error stating that the required bundle `com.company.antlr.runtime(3.0.1)` is
missing.

Adding `com.company.antlr.runtime (3.0.1)` as a bundle to the feature launch has no effect, I still get the same validation error.

If, on the other hand, I make a bundle based launch configuration including the exact same
bundles as those packaged in the feature there is no validation problem.

The problem can be illustrated with this minimal example:

The bundle `org.example.examplebundle` has the manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0 
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2 
Bundle-Name:Examplebundle 
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.example.examplebundle 
Bundle-Version:1.0.0.qualifier 
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7 
Require-Bundle: com.company.antlr.runtime;bundle-version="[3.0.1,3.0.1]"
```

And the feature `org.example.examplefeature` has the feature.xml:

```
<feature
      id="org.example.examplefeature"
      label="Examplefeature"
      version="1.0.0.qualifier">

   <plugin
         id="org.eclipse.osgi"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="org.example.examplebundle"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="com.company.antlr.runtime"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="3.0.1"
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="com.company.antlr.runtime"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="3.2.0"
         unpack="false"/>

</feature>
```

Making a feature based launch with just this feature will lead to the validation error.
Making a bundle based launch with the four bundles included in the feature does NOT give a validation error.

I then tried adding the necessary bundles for using the console and removing the bundle `org.example.examplebundle` from the feature `org.example.examplefeature` and then running it using the feature based launch. I then observed that the bundle `com.company.antlr.runtime (3.0.1)` was not started at all.

If I add the same necessary bundles to the bundle based launch I can observe that both  `com.company.antlr.runtime (3.0.1)` and `com.company.antlr.runtime (3.2.0)` are active.

My guess based on this is that the resolver for the feature based launch concludes that the bundle with the highest
version number is sufficient, and therefore doesn't start the older version at all.

With that hypothesis in mind, I tried to state explicitly in the feature.xml that I need a perfect match
for `com.company.antlr.runtime (3.0.1)` by including the following snippet in the feature.xml:

```
  <requires>
    <import 
      plugin="com.company.antlr.runtime"
      version="3.0.1"
      match="perfect"
      />
   </requires>
```

But, alas, to no avail.

So, my question now is: is there any way to solve this problem while keeping the feature based launch?

For completeness: I am running Eclipse Kepler 4.3 and OSGI 3.8.1

Comment: Rikke, did you find solution finally?

Comment: No, not really. In the end we had to update everything to use the latest version of antlr such that we no longer needed two versions of the bundle. Luckily this was doable in a reasonable amount of time. That might not always be the case!

Comment: I found bug in Eclipse [Product validation doesn't find plugin needed in two versions](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=367187) and provide patch for it. It seems it will be fixed in next version.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you are setting the auto-start to true for the two bundles when using Bundle based launcher. 
You can't do the same when using Feature based launcher unless you have set "Default Auto-Start" true or create a Product definition and set a start level for those bundles.

Comment: I have "Default Auto-Start" set to true for both feature and bundle based launch. Do you mean that I should be able to set auto-start explicitly for the bundles in the feature in that case?

Comment: well, I had issues with this "Default Auto-Start" once. So I started to create product files to test my feature based rcp. you can set the start level of individual bundles contained in a feature when using it. that .product file can be used to launch equinox (it will create a bundle based launch file in the workspace too).